# htaccess equivalent to PHP's $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a need to dynamically input the current domain name, into an htaccess file.  This would be trivial in PHP but I can't figure out how to do it in "Apache Speak" and my Apache-fu is weak.

For the record, I've tried this:

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer %{SERVER_NAME} internal

and this:

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer %{HTTP_HOST} internal

but frankly I'm not sure if I'm even on the right track at all.  The end result I'm after would look something like:

SetEnvIfNoCase Referer currentdomain.com internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try asking yourself, is there a different approach to your problem?

If there isn't a simple answer, it's most likely that there is a different way to approach the situation.

For example, if you could insert it dynamically once and write the .htaccess with php, you could possibly save yourself trouble and maybe even efficiency in your code.

Comment: OMG... totally didn't dawn on me to do this!  Brilliant, and simple.  I'll just create the .htaccess file from scratch the first time the script is run, and then I can use PHP to generate the domain name easily.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't one. If you're running 2.4 then you can use `SetEnvIfExpr`, but 2.2 or earlier require some work with mod_rewrite.

Comment: That's kindof what I was afraid of.  I'm not even sure exactly what version I'm running, and I have multiple servers anyway.  Could you possibly provide an example of using SetEnvIfExpr to accomplish what I'm trying to do?  I'm off to research it myself in the meantime.

Comment: You're probably not running 2.4. I'd look into mod_rewrite regardless, since it will be more portable.

Comment: yeah I don't think I'm running 2.4.  How would mod_rewrite help though?  I'm not looking to rewrite any URLs, I need to dynamically insert whatever the current domain is, into my htaccess file.  Am I misunderstanding your suggestion?

Comment: Use `RewriteCond` to check the referrer, and `RewriteRule` with a null rewrite to set the env var.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Referer www\.whateveryourdomain\.com internal
```

The syntax for `SetEnvIfNoCase` is like this:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase attribute regex [!]env-variable[=value] [[!]env-variable[=value]] ...
```

From [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif)
attribute can have:

> - An HTTP request header field (see [RFC2616](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt) for more information about these); for example: Host, User-Agent, Referer, and Accept-Language. A regular expression may be used to specify a set of request headers.
> - One of the following aspects of the request:
>
>   - Remote_Host - the hostname (if available) of the client making the request
>   - Remote_Addr - the IP address of the client making the request
>   - Server_Addr - the IP address of the server on which the request was received (only with versions later than 2.0.43)
>   - Request_Method - the name of the method being used (GET, POST, et cetera)
>   - Request_Protocol - the name and version of the protocol with which the request was made (e.g., "HTTP/0.9", "HTTP/1.1", etc.)
>   - Request_URI - the resource requested on the HTTP request line -- generally the portion of the URL following the scheme and host portion without the query string. See the RewriteCond directive of mod_rewrite for extra information on how to match your query string.
> - The name of an environment variable in the list of those associated with the request. This allows SetEnvIf directives to test against the result of prior matches. Only those environment variables defined by earlier SetEnvIf[NoCase] directives are available for testing in this manner. 'Earlier' means that they were defined at a broader scope (such as server-wide) or previously in the current directive's scope. Environment variables will be considered only if there was no match among request characteristics and a regular expression was not used for the attribute.

The same applies for `SetEnvIfNoCase`.

Comment: The problem is that the asker doesn't want to have to hardcode the server name.

Comment: Yes, Ignacio is exactly right.  I need this to be dynamic so that no matter what domain the script is running on, it will automatically have the correct information pulled into htaccess.